# Character marker as text in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

How can I add a combination of digits and alphabets using the edit symbol tool in ArcGIS. I can add a single number/alphabet for example 2 to it as shown in the screenshot, but I don't know how to add the whole combination to the symbol of that particular point which is for example 222 or 222A.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution, but you can copy/paste your character symbol in the symbol Layers (left hand side of the dialog). Then, apply a negative and positive X offset (right hand side of the dialog) for each of the characters.

[image]

Comment: So, for the last 2 in 222 the negative X offset is -16 or does it stay -8 each time?

Comment: No, you’ll have to play around with the numbers. I can’t remember what I had but it was something like -8, -2, 4, 10. But it’ll depend on your font and text size and what looks best. The numbers I used were just for demonstration.

Comment: Would you recommend using ArcGIS Pro for this kind of symbol editing? Or will I have to use the same method as described in your answer in ArcGIS Pro too?